# Custom UI AccountKit for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, account-kit

I am trying to customise the UI of AccountKit for iOS and I am finding some troubles as the documentation is not very clear (plus it's outdated).

I want to return view on the designed methods of the `AdvancedUIManager`. The issue I'm finding is:

- This methods are made to return a `UIView?`.
- If I am returning a `UIView`, nothing shows.
- If I return any other UI object like a `UILabel`, it works.

For example, this works:

```
func headerView(for state: LoginFlowState) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "HEEEY*"
        return label
    }
```

But this doesn't:

```
func bodyView(for state: LoginFlowState) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }
```

I want to be able to return a custom `UIView` on these methods:
`func headerView(for state: LoginFlowState) -> UIView?`
`func footerView(for state: LoginFlowState) -> UIView?`
`func bodyView(for state: LoginFlowState) -> UIView?`

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thank you